# Isolation levels and rows not yet read

Tags: sql-server, locking, transaction, isolation-level

Under RR in transaction T1 I do a

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE city='London'
```

In another T2 I do

```
UPDATE mytable SET price=100 WHERE city='London' and id=5000
```

Is it possible that T2 reads,updates and commits the row in question BEFORE T1 gets to read it ?

1.If that is so,then RR would not have an effect,or as a matter in this scenario no isolation level would have an effect becasue isolation concerns only rows that they've been ALREADY read,not those not yet read.True?

2.Is however SERIALIZIBLE different? Does it take key range locks which means it locks the rows BEFORE it has read them? So would SERIALIZIBLE in the code example above

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE city='London'
```

take any key ranges locks that would prevent the scenario of T2 getting to the row and updating before it is read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q1**

> Is it possible that T2 reads,updates and commits the row in question
> BEFORE T1 gets to read it ?

**A1**

Yes, as noted by Paul White [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/t-sql-queries/the-repeatable-read-isolation-level):

> The repeatable read isolation level provides a guarantee that data
> will not change for the life of the transaction once it has been read
> for the first time.

Also due to lock escalation the query can start with row locks and then escalate to a full table lock. If the update runs while row locks are being taken and the row has not been accessed yet, then the update will not be blocked.

**Q2**

> If that is so,then RR would not have an effect,or as a matter in this scenario no isolation level would have an effect becasue
> isolation concerns only rows that they've been ALREADY read,not those
> not yet read.True?

**A2**

Yes,
you could use full table locking with a `TABLOCK` hint to make sure that the entire table is locked in RR but that reduces concurrency.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable WITH(TABLOCK) WHERE city='London';
```

Of course, if you are selecting a lot of data anyway the table lock escalation might happen nonetheless.
This is commonly around the 5000 row mark but can be higher/lower.

**Q3**

> Is however SERIALIZIBLE different? Does it take key range locks which means it locks the rows BEFORE it has read them? So would
> SERIALIZIBLE in the code example above take any key ranges locks that
> would prevent the scenario of T2 getting to the row and updating
> before it is read?

**A3**

Yes, it takes range locks and the considerations for equality range locks are noted by Sunil Agarwal [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/range-locks/ba-p/383080):

> **Equality Predicate**
>
> - If the key value exists, then the range lock is only taken if the        index is non-unique. In the non-unique index case, the ‘range’ lock
>   is taken on the requested key and on the ‘next’ key. If the ‘next’
>   key does not exist, then a range lock is taken on the ‘infinity’
>   value. If the index is unique then a regular S lock on the key.
> - If the key does not exist, then the ‘range’ lock is taken on the    ‘next’ key both for unique and non-unique index. If the ‘next’ key
>   does not exist, then a range lock is taken on the ‘infinity’ value.

In your case the key exists, and the index is probably non-unique so you would have a range lock up to the next value or the infinity value.

However I would be wary of using the serializable isolation level, it can introduces deadlocks and other concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

SERIALIZABLE preserves new rows to be added to the result set while REPEATABLE READ preserves actuals rows to do not change or be deleted.